# Affecting the log path of a website in IIS7 With the MSBuildExtensionPack

Tags: iis, iis-7, msbuild, iis-7.5

I was wondering if it is possible to change the logging path for a website via the MSBuildExtensionPack tasks I was setting the LogFileDir path (from the sdc tasks) on sites in Iis6 but cannot see equivalent functionality in IIS7 tasks in the extension pack (Using April 2011 tasks for 3.5).

Is this a case of missing functionality in the pack and I have to roll my own solution or have I missed the method to set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation I think this is not possible (as it is in the sdc tasks) I came up with a solution using AppCmd.exe and psexec to execute after granting the correct permissions on redirect.config on the server.